# How to create a user with given password on SuSE from command line?

Tags: opensuse, users, password, useradd

I need to create bunch of new users with given password. What I want is a script that I would pass the user name of new user and it will create/add the user and set its password. (the password is the same for all new users - no security issues here.)

Any suggestions how to do that on SuSE from command line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does SuSE `useradd` have the `-p` option?  That takes the password (albeit in encrypted form, but you should be able to generate that I think).

So `useradd -p <crypt'ed password> <new username>` should do it I think

Comment: Yes, it does have it. `-p password    Encrypted password as returned by crypt(3)` any idea how I can generate it from a text?

Comment: This site appears to have everything you need: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-write-shell-script-to-add-user.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Type the username:"
read USERNAME
echo "Type the pass:"
stty -echo
read PWD
stty echo
useradd -p ${PWD} ${USERNAME}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done in two steps.

1. First create users with `useradd` command
2. On the second run something like this

   ```
   cat 1.txt | while read line; do echo "12345" | passwd --stdin $(echo ${line}); done
   ```

   where `1.txt` is a file containing the list of logins.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in `cat userlist`
do
useradd $i
echo "$i:your_password"|chpasswd
done
```

`userlist` should contain list of users to be created.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note, however, that the "backtick"-style for command substitutions is [deprecated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated), and the `$( ... )` style should be used instead.